# How to convert Pandas/python data manipulation to SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, data-manipulation

I know this is going to be a complex one. I have a bunch of python/pandas data manipulation which should be translated to SQL. I can go line by line and do the job. But is there any way to extract/get the SQL equivalent of a pandas data manipulation? For example:

```
tips.groupby("day").agg({"tip": np.mean, "day": np.size})
```

to

```
SELECT day, AVG(tip), COUNT(*)
FROM tips
GROUP BY day;
```

my queries can be more complex than this.
There is a pandas module to get schema but I'm not ever of something that can do this (`pd.io.sql.get_schema`)

Comment: Could you post a list of the pandas manipulations you have to perform? I want to see how similar/different they are to give you an idea of how to automate this.

Comment: well, stuff like this
```
full = data_small.groupby("code").agg(full_len=("target", len), full_median=(target, 'median')).reset_index()
full.full_median = np.where(full.full_len >= min_samples_for_median, full.full_median, np.nan)
full = full.rename(columns={'full_median': code + '_full_median'}).drop('full_len', axis=1)
```
doable in sql but I was thinking maybe there's a quicker way

Comment: You'd have to split the commands by key characters, such periods and parentheses. Then you'd have to translate each command into SQL, which would be time consuming, but certainly doable. If you want to go that route, it will involve a lot of recognizing functions and printing out statements as a result.

Answer (score 1):

There's an experimental library by Amir Pupko for this purpose here:

https://github.com/AmirPupko/pandas-to-sql

with examples here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-to-sql-moving-code-from-sql-to-python-and-pandas-afc4c62a644c

I just came across it myself and haven't had a chance to try it yet, but it looks like a pretty decent start.